# Issue creating an object to send to API

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I'm trying to come up with something in this format:

```
"hours":{
      "<default>":{
        "mon_open_close":[...],
        "tue_open_close":[...],
        "wed_open_close":[...],
        "thu_open_close":[...],
        "fri_open_close":[...],
        "sat_open_close":[...],
        "sun_open_close":[...],
      }
    }
```

I have a bunch of variables defined like this (one for each day of the week):

```
var wed_open_close_hours = [operationTime[2].timeFrom+'-'+operationTime[2].timeTill];
```

That yields something like: `[10:00-16:00]`

And then have this array:

```
 $all_hours_text = ['mon_open_close', 'tues_open_close' ,'wed_open_close' , 'thu_open_close' , 'fri_open_close' , 'sat_open_close' ,'sun_open_close'];
```

The issue I have is how to roll it all together and create this one single object. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Loop through the `$all_hours_text` array, use `eval()` to get the name from the correlating variable and put it all together with `unknown_var.hours["default"][value] = eval(value + "hours")`. But this is a very dirty way. I would suggest to change the whole file structure so it fits better together.

Comment: *"`[10:00-16:00]`"* - What's the point of an array that always has exactly one element? Anyway, *don't* use individual variables for each day of the week, use properties in an object in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

So if you set

```
var wed_open_close_hours = [operationTime[2].timeFrom+'-'+operationTime[2].timeTill];
```

in a global scope, it will also be available as

```
window.wed_open_close_hours;
```

Otherwise it's available if you did something like eval("wed_open_close_hours"); 
So you could do

```
all_hours_text.map(function(varname) {
      if(window[varname+"_hours"]) {

          result["hours"]["<default>"][varname] = window[varname+"_hours"];
      }
})
```

or

```
 all_hours_text.map(function(varname) {

          result["hours"]["<default>"][varname] = eval(varname+"_hours");

})
```

However, neither setting variables at the global scope nor using eval is recommended practice. You really should consider factoring the code to something like:

```
var output = {}
output.hours = {}
output.hours["<default>"] = {}

.,..
output.hours["<default>"].wed_open_close = [operationTime[2].timeFrom+'-'+operationTime[2].timeTill];
```